# onCheckedChangeListener not working with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

I've been following the NerdRanch Android Tutorial [Chapter 8, Wiring Widgets] and came upon this troublesome error.This is the error I am receiving:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnCheckedChangeListener' must
>   either be declared abstract or implement abstract method
>   'onCheckedChange(CompoundButton, boolean)' in
>   'OnCheckedChangeListener'

Here is the code for my CrimeFragment.java

```
package com.example.justin.criminalintent;

// imports...

import static android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(
                    CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(
                    CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after) {
                //This space intentionally left blank
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
                // This one too
            }
        });

        //Get a reference to the new button, set its text as date of the crime
        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        //Get a reference to the checkbox, and set a listener that will update
        // the mSolved field of the CRIME
        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //Set the crime's solved property
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

And here is the log from the Gradle Build:

```
C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\CriminalIntent\app\src\main\java\com\example\justin\criminalintent\CrimeFragment.java
Error:(65, 82) error: <anonymous com.example.justin.criminalintent.CrimeFragment$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton,boolean) in OnCheckedChangeListener
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line

```
 public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
```

to

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
```

Comment: Wow, Can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much!